# Retrieving text from XML with C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml

I have a text file that contains this:

```
<Person>
    <Prenom>Jack</Prenom>
    <Nom>Jhon</Nom>
    <Adresse>4 rue de la Mélandine</Adresse>
    <Tél></Tél>
    <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
    <PhotoPath>c:\Program Files\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire de tâche v2\Img\5295f1ea-372a-4f2f-8f32-c52e8a48cc0839105.png</PhotoPath>
    <Age>19</Age>
    <Id>4640434</Id>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Prenom>Jean</Prenom>
    <Nom>Delamar</Nom>
    <Adresse>13 rue de la Mélandine</Adresse>
    <Tél></Tél>
    <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
    <PhotoPath>c:\Program Files\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire de tâche v2\Img\5295f1ea-372a-4f2f-8f32-c52e8a48cc0839105.png</PhotoPath>
    <Age>19</Age>
    <Id>4640434</Id>
</Person>
```

I would like to retrieve all the values between the tags
For example, in a list, I would like to retrieve the values (here 2) between  and

How could I do this?

I tried this:

```
internal static void LoadPerson()
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(Main.PersonnePath);

        Regex regex = new Regex("<Person>(.*)</Person>");
        var v = regex.Match(data);
        string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
```

Except that s contains nothing at all

Can you help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: There are more than two values between `Person` tags. Your file is plain XML one, you can use `XmlSerializer` and deserialize you xml into object to get any string than

Comment: Why are you taking my hello away from me? No right to say hello?

Comment: As @PavelAnikhouski mentioned you need to usa an `XmlSerializer` -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The @PavelAnikhouski answer is right, except that it won't work here, as your XML is not proper. It has two Person tag, but they need to be one root tag. So XMLSerializer will fail. If it is just sample and original file have a wrapper tag like `<persons>` then XMLSerializer will work.

Comment: @SumitGupta I've added an answer with updated xml file

Comment: @SumitGupta As the question asks how to get data from xml using regex. I added another answer with some considerations about performance. And what should be considered before choose between the two approaches.

Comment: @LuttiCoelho OP didn't not ask to parse XML using regex, as he never mention it is XML, he refer it as text file instead. So OP (in my opinion ) doesn't know what XML is, but we know. That is what I try to point out. But thanks for your answer, hope it helps him.

Comment: @SumitGupta I agree with you. Maybe he doesn't know what XML is. Because of that I explain both ways in my answer. I also up vote Pavel's answer as it provide very good information handling XML with C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need this values as plain text. you can use Regular Expression or XMLSerializer or (Linq to XML).

What you need to analyse before choose one approach or the other is:

1) What I need to do with this?

1.a) If you only needs the plain text inside each  tag. And you will not do any validation / calc / re-parser. You can use both methods in a easy way.

1.a.1) Using Regular Expression:

```
    public List<string> GetValueByRegex(string input)
    {
        string pattern = @"<Person>([\s\S]*?)</Person>";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        if (matches.All(m => !m.Success))
            return null;

        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            result.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

1.a.2) Use XDocument to parse Xml string

> Important: XDocument requires that your XML have one root Tag to work. As Your XML has two root Tags. I forced it with string interpolation `$"<root>{input}</root>"`

```
    public List<string> GetValueByXmlParse(string input)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var ensureThereAreOnlyOneRootTag = $"<root>{input}</root>";

        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(ensureThereAreOnlyOneRootTag);
        foreach(var personXml in xmlDocument.Root.Elements("Person"))
        {
            result.Add(String.Concat(personXml.Nodes()));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

1.b) If you will do any thing with the data you extract from your XML should be better to parse it to an object.

> You can make Visual Studio generate one by copy the XML value and click in Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes.

@PavelAnikhouski already share a good example for that.

2) I really need a good performance for that?

To answer that I use a Benchmark nuget package to compare all options. This is the result:

```
|                Method |    Gen 0 | Allocated |
|---------------------- |---------:|----------:|
|       GetValueByRegex |   1.2207 |    2688 B |
|    GetValueByXmlParse | 115.6006 |  243536 B |
```

> Gen 0 : GC Generation 0 collects per 1000 operations
>
> Allocated : Allocated memory per single operation (managed only, inclusive, 1KB = 1024B)

So, the answer is: Depends on what you need to do with the result of that. I hope I could help you to decide.

Best Regards

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for this very detailed answer!
You really made me clear and everything works!

Comment: Welcome. Happy I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Since your file has an XML format, you can use `XmlSerializer` for reading that, it's less painful, than parse it manually

Create a `Person` class first (or generate using *Edit -> Paste special -> Paste XML as classes* in Visual Studio)

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    private string _prenomField;
    private string _nomField;
    private string _adresseField;
    private object _télField;
    private string _emailField;
    private string _photoPathField;
    private byte _ageField;
    private uint _idField;

    public string Prenom
    {
        get => _prenomField;
        set => _prenomField = value;
    }

    public string Nom
    {
        get => _nomField;
        set => _nomField = value;
    }

    public string Adresse
    {
        get => _adresseField;
        set => _adresseField = value;
    }

    public object Tél
    {
        get => _télField;
        set => _télField = value;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get => _emailField;
        set => _emailField = value;
    }

    public string PhotoPath
    {
        get => _photoPathField;
        set => _photoPathField = value;
    }

    public byte Age
    {
        get => _ageField;
        set => _ageField = value;
    }

    public uint Id
    {
        get => _idField;
        set => _idField = value;
    }
}
```

Than update a structure of file a little bit (you have to have one root tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
  <Person>
    <Prenom>Jack</Prenom>
    <Nom>Jhon</Nom>
    <Adresse>4 rue de la Mélandine</Adresse>
    <Tél></Tél>
    <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
    <PhotoPath>c:\Program Files\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire de tâche v2\Img\5295f1ea-372a-4f2f-8f32-c52e8a48cc0839105.png</PhotoPath>
    <Age>19</Age>
    <Id>4640434</Id>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Prenom>Jean</Prenom>
    <Nom>Delamar</Nom>
    <Adresse>13 rue de la Mélandine</Adresse>
    <Tél></Tél>
    <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
    <PhotoPath>c:\Program Files\Zonedetec\Gestionnaire de tâche v2\Img\5295f1ea-372a-4f2f-8f32-c52e8a48cc0839105.png</PhotoPath>
    <Age>19</Age>
    <Id>4640434</Id>
  </Person>
</people>
```

and finally parse it

```cs
var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]), new XmlRootAttribute("people"));
Person[] people;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Main.PersonnePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    people = (Person[])mySerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Xml.Serialization;` namespace. After deserialization `people` array will contain all values you need, you can format them to any string/whatever you want. The best option here is override `ToString()` method of `Person` class to get required string representation of object